# How to increment count only once while tapping on checkboxes in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, count

I have four checkboxes and there is a label which tells if the checkbox is clicked and displays the count(like 1,2). The problem is when I click on a checkbox and then click on other checkbox it displays the count again but I want to display the count only once even if I click on other checkbox.

I have created an array IBOutlet for the checkboxes:

```
@IBOutlet var checkbox:[UIButton]!
```

When I am tapping on the checkbox, this is the code I am using:

```
 @IBAction func checkboxTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        for button in checkbox {
            button.isSelected = false
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "selected"), for: .selected)
        }
      
        sender.isSelected = true   
         if index >= 0 {
               index += 1 // taken a index variable and incremented it
               answeredLbl.text = "\(index )" // label where I want to display the count
               }
    }
```

I have an idea of using tag for a button but not sure how to do that. Any help..

Answer (score 1):

Inside IB set tags for all the buttons from 1 to 4 then

```
answeredLbl.text = "\(sender.tag)"
```